# How to split tags from HTML

Tags: c#, tags

I have very simple text with HTML. Here i want the image alone to append in some other place.How could i cut the image tag alone using c #.

```
<p>this is new document<img alt="" height="150" src="https://kuba2storage.blob.core.windows.net/kuba-appid-1/manual-1203/images/desert-20180824203530071.jpg" width="200"/>This is new document</p>
```

I want to get the img tag alone from this data.For example

```
<img alt="" height="150" src="https://kuba2storage.blob.core.windows.net/kuba-appid-1/manual-1203/images/desert-20180824203530071.jpg" width="200"/>
```

code:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(text.Text, @"(<img>[\s\S]+?<\/img>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Comment: [NEVER EVER USE REGEX TO PROCESS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625).

Comment: Can u help me to solve this by another way

Comment: HTML is just a xml, you can use xml tools or check out [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a third party library like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), they have a few nice examples on their [Example page](https://html-agility-pack.net/online-examples), on such is

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GetLinks();
    }

    private static void GetLinks()
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html");
            List<string> htmls = new List<string>();
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
            {
                string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("src", string.Empty);
                htmls.Add(hrefValue);
            }
        foreach(var item in htmls){
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        if(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")==null){
        Console.WriteLine("no links");
        }
        }
}
```

this can be found on https://dotnetfiddle.net/QAZnDz , you can also use linq to filter the images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void  Main(string[] args)
        {
             string data = "<p>this is new document<img alt='' height='150' src='https://kuba2storage.blob.core.windows.net/kuba-appid-1/manual-1203/images/desert-20180824203530071.jpg' width='200'/>This is new document</p>";
             var newdt = FetchImgsFromSource(data);

        }
    }
    public static List<string> FetchImgsFromSource(string htmlSource)
    {
        List<string> listOfImgdata = new List<string>();
        string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
        var matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
        {
            string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
            listOfImgdata.Add(href);
        }
        return listOfImgdata;
    }
}
```

[image]